# Can't pickle in parallel computing. Can [dill] or other tool pickle [networkit] graphs?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pickle, networkit

I need to run a function in parallel for different input values. The thing is that I need to get the output (a NetworKit Graph) of the function for each iterations. I tried to use **`joblib`**, **`Multiprocessing.Process`** and **`Queue`**, **`pathos`**, but I always have the same error

> **`can't pickle _NetworKit.Graph objects`**

Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying to parallelize, with an example with `joblib` :

```
from networkit import Graph
from joblib    import Parallel, delayed

def f( i ):
    graph = networkit.Graph()
    graph.addNode()

    # ... Some other graph computations ...

    return graph

res = Parallel( n_jobs = 2 ) ( delayed( f )( i ) for i in np.arange( 5 ) )
```

I understand that all these libraries use **`pickle`** to serialize an object and that **`networkit`** objects are not pickable. I read that **`dill`** allows us to pickle non pickable objects, does anyone have any experience with `dill` using multiprocessing ?

Otherwise, is there any way to accomplish what I need ?

Thank you !

Comment: If it can't be pickled then you probably can't do much about it. But you can transform it into something that can be pickled. e.g. read the data from the graph that you need.

Comment: @de1 Thanks ! My problem is way more complex (streaming data) and I really need to get the graph as an output of the function.

Comment: For alternatives you could start having a look to this intro to dill and pathos http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization or this one https://kampta.github.io/Parallel-Processing-in-Python/ . I think McKeam is the author of both pathos and dill but while you do not have an answer this may help.